# In MS Word, insert current time, with seconds?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

In MS Word 2010, "Ctrl + Shift + ;" causes the current time to be inserted, with the seconds portion of the value as "00". Is there a quick way to insert the current time, with an accurate seconds value?

Answer (score 1):

Havent found the straight answer yet for your question, had the same problem earlier. However you can fix it by making macro for it:

```
Public Sub TimeStamp
    Selection.InsertDateTime _
      DateTimeFormat:="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" & _
      " - ", InsertAsField:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

On the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click the **Date & Time** button. In the dialog box, select the format that includes seconds, and then click **Set As Default**.

Then, the next time you have to insert the time, you just have to click **Date & Time**, and then click **OK** or press Enter. Pretty quick and doesn't require a macro.

Comment: Not sure if this works universally. Under the Insert Tab, in the Text group, I did not have a Date & Time button. I added a custom group, with a Date & Time button. Clicking the button brings up a bunch of functions (NOW(), TIME(), DATE(), etc.) pertaining to dates/times, and there's no apparent way to set defaults for formatting.